# How to use kubeadm upgrade to change some features in kubeadm-config

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubeadm

I want to install kube-prometheus on my existing kubernetes cluster(v1.10). Before that, the doc says I need to change the ip address of contrller/scheduler from `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0`. And it also recommand to use [kubeadm config upgrade](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-config/) to change these features:

```
controllerManagerExtraArgs:
  address: 0.0.0.0
schedulerExtraArgs:
  address: 0.0.0.0
```

After reading the doc, i tried with the below command, but it didn't work:

```
kubeadm upgrade --feature-gates controllerManagerExtraArgs.address=0.0.0.0
```

I know i can use `kubectl -n kube-system edit cm kubeadm-config` to modify configMap directly, just want to know how to upgrade it from `kubeadm upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of is to use the `--config` option.

Generate a yaml file that looks like this:

```
controllerManagerExtraArgs:
  address: 0.0.0.0
schedulerExtraArgs:
  address: 0.0.0.0
```

and then run:

```
kubeadm upgrade apply --config /etc/kubeadm.yaml
```

Comment: Just tried this on katacoda's k8s and got fatal errors: "The --version arguement is invalid due to these errors: sepcified version to upgrade to "v1.10.0" is higher than the kubeadm version "v1.10.0". I add the version v1.10.0 on the command it got stuck

Comment: Just force it: `kubeadm upgrade apply --config /etc/kubeadm.yaml --force`